# Azure Pipeline: Setting variable in one template, use it in expression in another

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

What I tried to achive:

1. Set variable featureName in template 1 called `set-variable.yml`
2. Pass variable featureName as parameter to template 2 called `check-variable.yml`
3. Check if featureName parameter is empty in a compile time expression in template 2.

pipeline.yml:

```
trigger:
  - '*' # Run on all Branches

pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: test1
  jobs:
  - job: test1
    steps:
    - template: set-variable.yml
    - template: check-variable.yml
      parameters:
        featureName: $(setVariables.featureName)
```

set-variable.yml:

```
steps:
- script: |
    featureName=''
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=featureName;isOutput=true]$featureName"
  displayName: Set variable 
  name: setVariables
```

check-variable.yml:

```
parameters:
- name: featureName
  type: string
  default: ''


steps:
- ${{ if ne(parameters.featureName, '') }}:
  - script: |
      echo "This should not be executed, but it is!"
    displayName: "featureName != ''"
```

The problem is, that the step `featureName != ''` in `check-variable.yml` gets executed, even though I set the `featureName` variable in the `set-variables.yml` template to be empty.

(Passing of the variable `featureName` as a parameter to template `check-variable.yml` is working, see debugging attempts below)

=== Debugging 1 ===

For debugging purpose, I've expanded the `check-variable.yml` with some debugging tasks.

check-variable.yml:

```
parameters:
- name: featureName
  type: string
  default: ''


steps:
- script: |
    echo "Check feature"
    echo "- featureNameDotted: [${{ parameters.featureName }}]"
    echo "- featureNameArray: [${{ parameters['featureName'] }}]"
    echo "- featureNameEnvDotted: [$featureNameEnvDotted]"
    echo "- featureNameEnvArray: [$featureNameEnvArray]"
    echo "- json: [${{ convertToJson(parameters.featureName) }}]"
    echo "- length: [${{ length(parameters.featureName) }}]"
    echo

    if [[ -z $featureNameEnvDotted ]]; then
      echo "featureNameEnvDotted is (empty or null)"
    else
      echo "featureNameEnvDotted not (empty or null)"
    fi
    echo

    if [[ $featureNameEnvDotted = '' ]]; then
      echo "featureNameEnvDotted = ''"
    else
      echo "featureNameEnvDotted != ''"
    fi
    echo

    if [[ $featureNameEnvDotted = 'hello' ]]; then
      echo "featureNameEnvDotted = 'hello'"
    else
      echo "featureNameEnvDotted != 'hello'"
    fi
  env:
    featureNameEnvDotted: ${{ parameters.featureName }}
    featureNameEnvArray: ${{ parameters['featureName'] }}
  displayName: "Debug: All"
  
- ${{ if eq(parameters.featureName, '') }}:
  - script: |
      echo 
    env:
      featureName: ${{ parameters.featureName }}
    displayName: "Debug: Empty!!"

- ${{ if ne(parameters.featureName, '') }}:
  - script: |
      echo 
    env:
      featureName: ${{ parameters.featureName }}
    displayName: "Debug: Not empty!!"
  
- ${{ if eq(parameters.featureName, 'hello') }}:
  - script: |
      echo 
    env:
      featureName: ${{ parameters.featureName }}
    displayName: "Debug: Equals 'hello'"

- ${{ if ne(parameters.featureName, '') }}:
  - script: |
      echo "This should not be executed, but it is!"
    displayName: "featureName != ''"
```

The output of the task `Debug: All` is:

> Check feature
>
> - featureNameDotted: []
> - featureNameArray: []
> - featureNameEnvDotted: []
> - featureNameEnvArray: []
> - json: []
> - length: [27]
>
> featureNameEnvDotted is (empty or null)
>
> featureNameEnvDotted = ''
>
> featureNameEnvDotted != 'hello'

The bash if's work all well. featureName is empty and it is not 'hello'. The 'length' one I don't understand.

And the following tasks get executed:

- Set variable
- Debug: All
- Debug: Not empty!!
- featureName != ''

Why do the tasks `Debug: Not empty!!` and `featureName != ''` get executed, but task `Debug: Empty!!` not? featureName parameter IMO is empty!

=== Debugging 2 ===

I've left `check-variable.yml` the same. But I set `featureName` in the `set-variable.yml` template to the value "hello". With this I wanted to check if the variable `featureName` does get properly passed to the parameter of the template `check-variable.yml`

set-variable.yml:

```
steps:
- script: |
    featureName='hello'
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=featureName;isOutput=true]$featureName"
  displayName: Set variable 
  name: setVariables
```

The output of the task `Debug: All` is:

> Check feature
>
> - featureNameDotted: [hello]
> - featureNameArray: [hello]
> - featureNameEnvDotted: [hello]
> - featureNameEnvArray: [hello]
> - json: [hello]
> - length: [27]
>
> featureNameEnvDotted not (empty or null)
>
> featureNameEnvDotted != ''
>
> featureNameEnvDotted = 'hello'

This again looks well. The parameter does hold the value 'hello' and the if's look good (still, length I don't understand).

And here the list of tasks which get executed:

- Set variable
- Debug: All
- Debug: Not empty!!
- featureName != ''

Why is `Debug: Equals 'hello'` not executed?

`parameters.featureName` holds something like the value 'hello', but it is not exactly the string 'hello'. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The `${{ length(parameters.featureName) }}` which evaluates to 27 pushed me in the right direction. 27 is the length of the string `$(setVariables.featureName)` which is passed to the template `check-variable.yml`.

This can be tested with the following expression which I put into `check-variable.yml`:

```
- ${{ if eq(parameters.featureName, '$(setVariables.featureName)') }}:
  - script: |
      echo 
    env:
      featureName: ${{ parameters.featureName }}
    displayName: "Debug: Equals 'dollar(setVariables.featureName)'"
```

This always executes, when featureName was set or if it was empty.

I think what happens is that when the compile time expressions like `${{ ... }}` are evaluated inside a template, the parameter featureName is evaluated to `$(setVariables.featureName)`. This is the case in the `${{ if ... }}` expressions as well as in the script tasks with `${{ parameters...}}`. After the `${{ ... }}` expressions have been evaluated, it starts executing the script tasks. There it finds the variable `$(setVariables.featureName)` and evaluates it. But evaluation of the `$(setVariables.featureName)` is never done for the compile time expressions with an if statement. There it just takes the name of the variable.

So to get it to work I did a work around where I set a variable in a script task, and use a task condition to evaluate it.

check-variable.yml:

```
parameters:
- name: featureName
  type: string
  default: ''


steps:
- script: |
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=featureName]${{ parameters.featureName }}"
  displayName: "Set featureName var"

- script: |
    echo "Only execute me when featureName is not empty"
  displayName: "featureName != ''"
  condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables.featureName, ''))
```

Comment: Yes; the crucial difference is that the parameter is being evaluated at compile time, long before the variable exists or has a value. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions for some discussion of this, following the links where it says "Expressions can be evaluated at compile time or at run time."